# What is a method to export a SolidWorks part (with distinguishing between materials) to a voxel cloud?

Tags: solidworks

i'm doing a simulation in matlab which uses a 3D matrix as input, i.e. the matrix has the form (xDim, yDim, zDim).
With a simple STL export and a voxelization of this STL file i can get only a matrix with all elements be either one or zero.
But my part has four different materials which i need to distinguish in matlab.
One single slice in the matrix should look like:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 0 ...
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 0 0 ...
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
.
.
.
```

As a first step: in which format should i export my part to preserve the materials as some value?

Comment: Can you export the four materials as separate STLs, modify the 1's in the other materials as you wish, and combine the matrices?

Comment: STEP AP214 preserves colours upon export, which I use for differentiating between components when importing models into programs for rendering, but I don't have experience with then converting that to a voxel cloud

Comment: Did you distinguish materials in the part using split bodies?

Comment: Using four different exports was my first thought, too. But is is a bit cumbersome when editing the part.
I will have a look at STEPAP214, thanks.
I have four separate bodies with four different materials applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are stuck with using STL, here's a crude way to do it:

[image]

Steps:

- Create two references which extend beyond the object in the x, y, z space (I used the cylinders shown on the upper right and lower left corners)
- For each material (body), export STL along with the references
- Voxelise using the same parameters

The references are used to ensure that the binary voxel arrays are generated in a consistent space between the different bodies.

You can multiply each separate voxel array using a different number (2,3,4 ...) and then add them together. If you want to get rid of the references, you can use Matlab's `bwlabel` [function](https://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) to detect unconnected regions and remove them.

Comment: May i ask, how you voxelize the STLs? At the moment I use a python script in between SolidWorks and matlab.

Comment: @MarvinNoll I just Googled it and took the [first result](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27390-mesh-voxelisation?s_tid=mwa_osa_a) that came up.